# Copiar Valores de un Dataframe a otro según condición en Python

Tags: python

Tengo un dataframe con una serie de datos, que algunos coinciden con los datos de otro dataframe, lo que necesito es que si se cumple una condición, me traiga los datos que indico del segundo dataframe:

Lo que intenté hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
     for j in range (0, len(cc)):    
        if df['CUENTA'][i] == cc['RUBRO'][j]:
           df[['CUENTA', 'CENTRO']] = cc[['CUENTA', 'CENTRO']]
```

He probado diferentes formas, pero siempre vuelvo a este error o similares:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1317.0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-1eddc8288720> in <module>
     2     for j in range (0, len(cc)):
      3 
----> 4             if df['CUENTA'][i] == cc['RUBRO'][j]:
      5                 df[['CUENTA', 'CENTRO']] = cc[['CUENTA', 'CENTRO']]
      6 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py in get_value(self, series, key)
    447 
    448         k = com.values_from_object(key)
--> 449         loc = self.get_loc(k)
    450         new_values = com.values_from_object(series)[loc]
    451 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    506         except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    507             pass
--> 508         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    509 
    510     @cache_readonly

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
  2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()
   KeyError: 1317.0
```

Comment: Hola, comparte una captura de tus dataframe para poder visualizar mejor el problema y poder ayudarte

Comment: import pandas as pd

`df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df1['CUENTA'] = ('c','e','a','b','c')
df2['RUBRO'] = ('a','b','c','d','e')
df2['CUENTA'] = [1,2,3,4,5]`


Lo que necesito es que cuando coinciden los valores de la columna CUENTA del Dataframe A con la columna RUBRO en Dataframe B, me convierta los valores del Datafraeme A en la columna CUENTA con los valores que figuran en la columna CUENTA del Dataframe B

Answer (score 1):

para poder unir dos dataframes puedes hacerlo con la función `merge` pasando como parametros las columnas que quieras unir y opcionalmente los sufijos que tomaran las columnas que se unieron.

Partiendo de tu codigo quedaria algo asi:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df1 = pd.DataFrame() 
df2 = pd.DataFrame()  
df1['CUENTA'] = ('c','e','a','b','c') 
df2['RUBRO'] = ('a','b','c','d','e') 
df2['CUENTA'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Con esto ya nada mas falta hacer uso de la función `merge` de la siguiente manera

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2,left_on="CUENTA",right_on="RUBRO",suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))
```

Lo cual te da la siguiente salida

```
    CUENTA_df1  RUBRO   CUENTA_df2
0        c        c         3
1        c        c         3
2        e        e         5
3        a        a         1
4        b        b         2
```

Comment: Ivan, gracias por tu respuesta. Había intentado realizar un merge pero no me funciona, en primer lugar ese ejemplo cambia el orden de los datos, cosa que en mi dataframe eso no podría pasar. Pero además, cuanto intento hacer el merge, solo me carga los nombres de las columnas, no me trae ningún dato. :/

Comment: Recuerda que el merge lo puedes hacer hacia la izquierda o derecha, solo cambia el orden de los DF `df_merged = df2.merge(df1,right_on="CUENTA",left_on="RUBRO",suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))` ahora para poder ayudarte necesitaria conocer tus DF reales para ayudarte a dar una solución.

Comment: Ivan, gracias nuevamente por tu ayuda. Te dejo el link a los Dataframe. Un saludo y gracias nuevamente. https://github.com/jlacuesta/Stackoverflow

Comment: Estimado si se corre el merge tal cual como lo puse arriba si te une los dos DF y te genera las siguientes columnas `Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'ASIENTO', 'FECHA', 'CUENTA_df1', 'CONCEPTO', 'MONEDA',
       'DEBE', 'HABER', 'TIPO', 'COTIZACION', 'CENTRO_df1', 'REFERENCIA',
       'LOCAL', 'RUT', 'TRIBUTO', 'ORIGEN', 'CONTACTO', 'RUBRO', 'NOMBRE',
       'CENTRO_df2', 'CUENTA_df2'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: Gracias Ivan, eso sucede tal cuál lo comentas, lo que no me trae datos. Solo me aparecen las columnas vacías.

Comment: Cargue los datos y funciona bastante bien, debes recordar que antes de hacer un merge de DF debes hacer la limpieza de los mismos, por ejemplo, veo que los DF tiene datos `NaN`

Comment: Perfecto, tenía un error anterior que ya quedó corregido y ahora me funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias Ivan. Has sido muy amable.